# Directory permission shared between Windows Service and console application

Tags: windows-services, file-permissions, user-accounts

I'm not sure if this is proper place for such question (maybe should be placed on SuperUser?), but I'll try.

I have one C# console application and one Windows service. Both does the same, but console app was created before and is kept for backward compatibility. Each of these is running WCF service, whose methods operates on files in C:\ProgramData\MyApp. Console app is run as  limited user (non-admin), Windows service runs as NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. When app creates some dirs/files, service cannot delete it and vice versa.

I would like to have it secured. My question is: should I grant full permissions on C:\ProgramData\MyApp to NETWORK SERVICE and current user? Or should I create dedicated user for running service/app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your application does not set explicit security permission on newly created files, granting Network Service account Delete permissions on the folder would solve your immediate problem.

This command will do the work:

```
icacls c:\ProgramData\MyApp /t /grant "NETWORK SERVICE":(OI)(CI)(IO)D
```

Repeat the same for your other user service account.

Comment: Is this safer approach than creating Windows user "MyAppUser", grant him full rights to directory c:\ProgramData\MyApp and run service/application with this user's account (instead of NETWORK SERVICE)?

Comment: The most secure configuration for a service is always create a special user account and grant this account only enough permissions to work, and not more than this. However you need to be careful and not grant more permissions that they need. E.g. if you make your service account member of administrators group that defeats the purpose of special account. In many cases built-in accounts like LocalService or NetworkService are good enough.